# htmlspecialchars not converting

Tags: php, html-entities

I have this PHP code:

```
echo  htmlspecialchars("commen<p>commpen", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

but it echos out this: `commen<p>commpen`

Unless I am wrong, that is not what it is meant to output. It should escape the `<>` to `&lth;` `&gth;`

The only way I have figured out to get around this is by using this header:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

Is there a way to do it without the header?

Comment: View the source of the page without the text/plain encoding set and you will probably see `&lt;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* outputting `&lt;`. But your browser is interpreting it as the entity it is and rendering `<`.

Seriously, try not encoding it, see what happens.

Comment: They do exactly what we tell them to do. Learning how to tell them to do what we *want* them to do is where the skill comes in.